# Custom Vue Material md-Input how to get isDirty or isTouched

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-material

I would like to create my own CustomMdInput, with basic validation. I would like to implement a input that work that way:

I use a `<fp-input v-model="test"></fp-input>`, and It is important, that when this input is required, when someone clicked on it or typesomething (turns 'touched' or 'dirty' property), and next defocus this input and go to the another input, the previous one stays Invalid with all the validation, so i have something like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="md-layout-item">
    <md-field>
      <label :for="id">Imię</label>
      <md-input :name="id" :id="id" :required="required" v-model="value" :ref="id" @input="emitValue()"></md-input>
      <span class="md-error">Imię jest obowiązkowe</span>
    </md-field>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'FpInput',
  props: {
    value: {
      required: true
    },
    id: {
      required: true,
      type: String
    },
    required: {
      default: false,
      type: Boolean
    }
  },
  methods: {
    emitValue () {
      this.$emit('input', this.$refs[this.id].value)
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

But i don't know how to check if this input isDirty or isTouched, and how can i set Validity of this input to check isFormValid after submit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give you an example

```js
const MyInput = {
   template: '#myInput',
   props: ['value'],
   data () {
    return {
     inputValue: this.value,
     dirty: false,
     touched: false,
     inValid: false
    }
   },
   methods: {
    validate () {
     if(this.inputValue.length<5){
      this.inValid = true
      this.dirty = true
     }else{
      this.inValid = false
      this.dirty = false
      this.touched = false
     }
    },
    emitValue() {
     this.validate()
     this.$emit('input', this.inputValue);
    }
   }
  }

  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {MyInput},
    data () {
      return {
      }
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
 <div id="app">
   <my-input value="5"></my-input>
 </div>

 <script type="text/x-template" id="myInput">
  <div>
        <input v-model="inputValue" @input="emitValue()" @touchstart="touched = true" @mousedown="touched = true"/>
   <span v-show="(dirty || touched) && inValid">must be at least 5 letters</span>
   <div>dirty:{{dirty}}</div>
   <div>touched:{{touched}}</div>
   <div>inValid:{{inValid}}</div>
  </div>
 </script>
```

give you a full example

```js
const MyInput = {
  template: '#myInput',
  props: ['value'],
  data () {
    return {
      inputValue: this.value,
      dirty: false,
      touched: false,
      inValid: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    validate () {
      if(('' + this.inputValue).length<5){
        this.inValid = true
        this.dirty = true
      }else{
        this.inValid = false
        this.dirty = false
        this.touched = false
      }
    },
    emitValue(e) {
      this.validate()
      this.$emit('input', this.inputValue);
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.inputValue = this.value;
    this.validate();
    this.dirty = false;
  }
}

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {MyInput},
  data () {
    return {
      inputList: new Array(4).fill('').map(o=>({val:5}))
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submit () {
      if(this.$refs.inputs.some(o=>o.inValid)){
        alert('you have some input invalid')
      }else{
        alert('submit data...')
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
 <div id="app">
  <form @submit.prevent="submit">
      <my-input ref="inputs" v-for="item in inputList" v-model="item.val"></my-input>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
  </form>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="myInput">
  <div>
        <input v-model="inputValue" @input="emitValue()" @touchstart="touched = true"/>
    <span v-show="(dirty || touched) && inValid">must be at least 5 letters</span>
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Ok that will work, but also i would love to click submit in my parrent component and this will check if all of the inputs are valid, do you have any idea how can i do this?

Comment: Unfortunately, this.$refs in parrent component can't see any object, returns empty object {} :/ I'm considering using rxJS but i don't know how to do that, something like VeeValidate validateAll(), but this library doesn't see my child input components also

Comment: Take a look at the example I just submitted.It works well