# How to handle two input fields with one method in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am creating a login form using Vue.js and also validating it.

What I want is if the input field is empty show an error (input field gets a red border) but the problem is the logic behind it's creation.

How can I handle two input fields and check them whether they are empty or not using just one method in Vue.js? Let's say there will be ten inputs and I cannot just write ten methods!

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    email: '',
    password: '',
    hasError: false
  },
  methods: {
   validateFields() {
     if(!this.email && !this.password) {
         this.hasError = true;
        } else {
         this.hasError = false;
        }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.hasError {
    border-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
    <input type="text" v-model="email" @input="validateFields" :class="{hasError: hasError}">
    <input type="password" v-model="password" @input="validateFields" :class="{hasError: hasError}">
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see, it shows unusual behavior as the password field shows error although I have not yet inputted anything in the field. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use custom input component with validate or use the third party validate components,see [Custom Vue Material md-Input how to get isDirty or isTouched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239044/custom-vue-material-md-input-how-to-get-isdirty-or-istouched/50244154#50244154)